# How to call getter of function in other file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this function in my index.js :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const getters = {
  aPrice:null,
  bPrice:null
}

const setters = {
  aPrice:null,
  bPrice:null
}

export const Toto = () => {
  [getters.aPrice , setters.aPrice] = useState(null);
  [getters.bPrice , setters.bPrice] = useState(null);

  // runs once
  useEffect(() => {
    setters.aPrice(50));
    setters.bPrice(40);
  }, []);

  return (
    <SectionWrapper>
      ...
    </SectionWrapper>
  )
}
```

And I woudlike to get aPrice in this file main.js :

So I already import this : `import {Toto, getters} from` index.js

When I try to console it :

```
console.log(getters.aPrice);
```

I have the value `null` ?

Comment: Try using the full pathname for index js and see if that makes a difference. Something like file:///Home/Project/ProjectRootDirectory/index.js. As far as your code goes, everything looks in order, but I am not a Peer-Reviewer. I do know that when I have an issue such as the one you are experiencing, its almost always a problem with how I am inputting the pathname.

Comment: @NodeSamurai I have the value null now ?

Comment: Well that's good, that means its working. In the code above, you have it set to null...

Comment: @NodeSamurai yes wouldike to set the value of 50 and 40 after because the value will change every hours

Comment: You have `const getters = { aPrice:null }`. And so `getters.aPrice` is `null`. What do you expect `getters.aPrice` to be?

Comment: @devBsc Everything is set to null, and I have never used the React Framework methods useEffect and useState, so I don't know what they are doing under the hood, or what you expect them to do, i can however; clearly see that you have initialized/set your values to null, which is why they are returning null.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

1. aprice and bprice are not set.

### Solution

Remove this part.

```
const setters = {
  aPrice:null,
  bPrice:null
}
```

And use this part for setting the data.

```
export const Toto = () => {
  [getters.aPrice , setAprice] = useState(null);
  [getters.bPrice , setBprice] = useState(null);

  // runs once
  useEffect(() => {
    setAprice(50));
    setBPrice(40);
  }, []);

  return (
    <SectionWrapper>
      ...
    </SectionWrapper>
  )
}
```